# Ubuntu 22.04 docker install HDP 2.6.5 with error "failed to get D-BUS connection: No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, dbus, ambari, hdp

I've been downloaded and ran HDP 2.6.5 docker ,
But I've been struggling and received the following error for this line of command:

- docker exec -t sandbox-hdp sh -c rm -rf /var/run/postgresql/*; systemctl restart postgresql;
  Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory

The following are owner permission for each
srwxrwxr-x 1 root root 0 ဒီ    24 08:13 /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
drwxrwsr-x  3 postgres          postgres    120 ဒီ    24 10:16 postgresql
drwxrwxr-x 4 zpo zpo 4096 ဒီ    24 10:33 HDP_2.6.5_deploy-scripts_180624d542a25

I've been tried some steps but not solved,which resulted in unsuccessful start of ambari-server and localhost:1080

Answer (score 0):

The HDP Sandbox has not been updated in half a decade. You shouldn't be removing files from it, though.

You can find other Docker Compose stacks that start HDFS, Hive, Postgres, and other services you really need *individually*. In my opinion, Ambari should run from the host, not in a Docker container